# How to grant user in byethost

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, cpanel

I am trying to `import mydb.sql` in phpMyAdmin however I need to grant a user.  I am using a rental server called Byethost which uses cPanel. How can I grant permission to users?

Comment: [MySQL Databases - cPanel x3 Documentation](https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/ALD/MySQL+Databases+-+x3)

Answer (score 0):

Its Simple by following the steps below

1) Go to URL your domain name or IP /cpanel

> ex: mydomain.com/cpanel or xxx.xx.xx.xx/cpanel

2) Login with your username and password

3) Under the "Databases" tab click on "MySQL Databases" option

4) Under the "New Database" option type the desired database name you wish and click on "Create Database"

5) Then coming back to the same page under "Add New User" option enter the desired user name you want to give access to that db and enter the desired password below and then click on "Create User"

6) Now coming back to the same page if you move further downwards there will be a heading named "Add user to database" under that will be two dropdowns "User" and "Database" . Select the User name and Database name created in above steps and then click on "Add"

7) Now it will be redirected to the Grant user privileges page. This is where you need to grant access to the user to the db .

8) Select "Check ALL" / "Select ALL" or choose the desired privilege you need to give to that user and click on submit button .

That's it . Now if you go to PHPmyAdmin there will a database with the name you created and it will be already been granted privilege with the user you created.

Further if you need to give connections to the db in your code you can use the credentials you used for creating the db and the user .

***Note :*** For config file in your code the db name user name will be like

> "cpanelusername_dbname" and "cpanelusername_dbuser"